# How to make filter on single column with multiple value in REST API

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest

I have array of items ID now i just want that items from custom list using REST API.

array size not fixed in my scenario.

any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to build filter query from array of ids and apply filter as shown below:

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('SharePoint List Name')/items?$select=Title&$filter=((ID eq 1) or (ID eq 2))
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: i know this way i want any other way this  i think not good because i dont know how much ids comes from web  so it make url long

Comment: I don't think any other method will support this kind of filter.
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('SharePoint List Name')/items(1) : It is only allow one value

Answer (score 0):

**May be  you can create a dynamic CAML query from your array using javascript. Which may be look like below query:**

```
<View><Query>
    <Where>
        <In>
          <FieldRef Name="ID" />
          <Values>
            <Value Type="Number">4</Value>
            <Value Type="Number">6</Value>
            ...
            ...
            ...
          </Values>
        </In>
    </Where>
</Query></View>
```

**And then combine this CAML query with REST. Here CAML query will be act like a filter for your REST Url.**

Please look below example that combines CAML query with Sharepoint REST API :

```
function _rest_Post(rquest) {
    return $.ajax({
        method: rquest.method,
        url: rquest.url,
        contentType: rquest.contentType,
        headers: rquest.header,
        data: JSON.stringify(rquest.body),
    });

}

function GetByCaml(serviceParams) {
    var req = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: url + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('" + serviceParams.create.lName + "')/getitems",
        header: {
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
        },
        body: serviceParams.create.body,
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",

    };
    return _rest_Post(req);

}

function getData(){
    var queryViewXml = myDynamicQuery; //this will be your dynamically generated caml query
    var params = {};
    params.create= {};
    params.create.lName = "MyList";
    params.create.filter = "";
    params.create.body = {
        'query':{ 
            '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.CamlQuery' },
            'ViewXml': queryViewXml
        }
    }
    return GetByCaml(params);
};


getData().then(function(data){
    //success handler
}, function(error){
    //failure handler
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one workaround,

```
var filterQuery = "";

for(var i= 0; i<arrIds.length; i++)
{
    if(i == 0)
    {
        filterQuery ="ID eq "+arrIds[i];
    }
    else
    {
        filterQuery = filterQuery +" or ID eq "+arrIds[i];        
    }
}
```

loop the ID's in the array & make filter query. Then use it in the url for the API request.

```
url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl+"/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('LISTNAME')/Items?$filter="+filterQuery;
```

May be this will help...